# tesseract batch run on Windows

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to run tesseract cmd line on Windows. Program runs but returns blank c:\temp\temp2.txt file. Please help, where is the problem?

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>for %i in (d:\temp\temp*.*) do (tesseract %i >> c:\temp\temp2.txt -l eng+hin)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>(tesseract d:\temp\temp\Screenshot_20230601_102548.jpg  -l eng+hin 1>>c:\temp\temp2.txt )
read_params_file: Can't open eng+hin
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0.20181030 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 434

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>(tesseract d:\temp\temp\Screenshot_20230601_102638.jpg  -l eng+hin 1>>c:\temp\temp2.txt )
read_params_file: Can't open eng+hin
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0.20181030 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 492

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>(tesseract d:\temp\temp\Screenshot_20230601_102708.jpg  -l eng+hin 1>>c:\temp\temp2.txt )
read_params_file: Can't open eng+hin
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0.20181030 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 324
Detected 79 diacritics`

If I run tessseract on individual file, it returns the file with converted text.

I tried to do by changing the parameters like 0>>, 1>>, 2>> for output file redirection, it does not run. But with a>> etc., the program runs but there is no converted text.

Answer (score 1):

With one little change, the tesseract command in batch mode is working and that is:

> tesseract d:\temp\Internal_Storage\Screenshots\Screenshot_20230601_225213.jpg stdout  -l eng+hin 1>>c:\temp\temp2.txt

by applying stdout 1 >> c:\temp\temp2.txt